# Is there any closed expression for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^{k^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $r$ be any real number with $0 < r < 1$.
Then, of course, there is a closed expression for
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k = \frac{1}{1-r}$$
But does there also exist a closed expression for
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^{k^2} \qquad ?$$
Decent approximations will be appreciated as well.

Comment: That's more-or-less a *theta function* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function

Comment: CAS says: $\frac{1}{2} (\vartheta _3(0,r)+1)$ where: $\vartheta _3(0,r)$ is theta function.