# A weird summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I was trying to solve an integral I found on the internet. It was going pretty well until the final result came along with this sum.

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}e^{-k^2}}{k}$$

I have never seen such a series before. And I have no idea how to approach for solving this.

I tried Wolfram|Alpha to see if this actually converges or not, and it turns out this converges.

This looked similar to the Maclaurin series of $\ln(1+x)$ but manipulating it led me nowhere.

Is there a closed form for the general sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{k^2}}{k}$$

Where $|x| \le 1 $?

Comment: It is easy to see that it converges: it is an alternating series where the size of the terms tends to zero (very quickly).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3231942/is-there-any-closed-expression-for-sum-k-0-infty-rk2?noredirect=1

Comment: The largest terms are small $n$, and the sum converges so quickly that you may approximate it with the partial sum of just the first few terms. Even the first two terms have an error that is under $0.1 \% $.  Without the $k$ in the denominator, Mathematica evaluates the sum as an elliptic theta function.

Comment: @Sal seems like this sum is a rough one.

Comment: The (absolute) convergence is easy to see by comparison with the geometric series $\sum_k e^{-k}$. (One can also use the alternating series test, as @md2perpe commented, but remember that the absolute values of the summands must *decrease* to $0$, not just tend to $0$.)

Comment: these sums are related to the theta function